# orthogonal polynomial of the second kind

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, measure-theory, recurrence-relations, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $L:  \mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive definite linear functional and let that $\{s_n\}$ be a positive semi-definite sequence such that $L(x^n)= s_n, n\ge 0.$ Given a positive definite sequence, I was able to use the Gram-Schimdt orthogonalization method to construct a sequence of orthogonal polynomials $\{p_n\}$ whose leading coefficient is positive due to the  positivity nature of the sequence given. It turns out that this sequence of orthogonal polynomials  $\{p_n\}$ satsifies a three term recurrence relation given below
\begin{equation}
xp_n(x) =b_np_{n+1}(x)+a_np_n(x)+b_{n-1}p_{n-1}(x) , \quad n\ge 0
\end{equation}

We can see the sequence $p_n(x)$ as a solution to the three term recurrence relations stated above. Akhiezer http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/akhiezer.pdf as my reference introduced another solution to this three term recurrence relation by defining another solution by \begin{equation} q_n(x)= \displaystyle L\left(\frac{p_n(x)-p_n(y)}{x-y}\right)
\end{equation} where the  quotient $\frac{p_n(x)-p_n(y)}{x-y}$  is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ and $q_n(x)$ is a polynomial in variable $x$ and its degree is $n-1$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ so that we have $ \displaystyle xq_n(x) =b_nq_{n+1}(x)+a_nq_n(x)+b_{n-1}q_{n-1}(x), n\ge 1$ with $q_0(x)=0$ and $q_1(x)= \frac{1}{b_0}$

My question is how can the  linear functional $L$ be defined on rational functions since its domain is $\mathbb{R}[x]$. I have troubles understanding  this definition even though I actually confirmed the definition is true by computing $q_1,q_2$.You can please check Akhiezer page 8 for more clarification. Details and explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $P\in\mathbb{R}[X]$, $\frac{P(x)-P(y)}{(x-y)}$ is a polynomial on $X$ and $Y$, to see this let begin by a simple case, $P(x)=1$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{P(x)-P(y)}{x-y}&=&\frac{1-1}{x-y}\\
&=& 0 \\
&\in & \mathbb{R}[X,Y]
\end{eqnarray}
Let now $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $P(x)=x^n$, we will use this lemma

> $$
> x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dots+x^{n-1-i}y^i+\dots+y^{n-1})
> $$

so 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{P(x)-P(y)}{x-y}&=&\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}\\
&=& (x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dots+x^{n-1-i}y^i+\dots+y^{n-1}) \\
&\in & \mathbb{R}[X,Y]
\end{eqnarray}
Now Let $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ be any polynomial so 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{P(x)-P(y)}{x-y}&=&\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i-\sum_{i=0}^n a_i y^i}{x-y}\\
&=&\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i (x^i- y^i)}{x-y} \\
&=& \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i (x-y)Q_i(x,y)}{x-y} \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^n a_i Q_i(x,y)
&\in & \mathbb{R}[X,Y]
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the whole expansion and computation @Hamza but how does the application of $L$ on the last identity that you got yield the desired result that we want that $L [\frac{p_n(x)-p_n(y)}{x-y}]$ equals $q_n(x)$, a polynomial of degree n in variable x only.

Comment: Could you please check the Akhiezer book for more details? Maybe you might understand my question clearly.

Comment: I know the book of Akhiezer, the functional $L$ is applied to the variable $y$ not for $x$, for example $L(xy^2)=s_2x $